# Restore previous LXDE theme?

Tags: lubuntu, icons, themes, lxde

Just did a clean install of Lubuntu from a newly downloaded iso image, 16.04.6, but can't find my old theme & icons in the appearance modifier. 
As a massive autist who hates change, this is killing me.
 I noticed the theme was different but I recalled changing it to one of the default options last time I installed, so expecting to be able to do the same again, I took no record of what they were. 
This time I could not find the same theme/icons.
 I did a precursory search for LXDE themes and quickly found this image, and multiple others showing the previous appearance, but no details of what the previous theme/icons were called or where to find & install them. 
This is what my desktop, icons and task bar used to look like;

[image: you're the one that i want]

How do I get them back?

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS is still supported, in desktop, server and Kylin, all flavors of Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (including Lubuntu) had only 3 years of support, thus I would suggest upgrading to Lubuntu 18.04 LTS for security reasons unless you want to use Unity (Ubuntu), Kylin or no-desktop (server).  Yes your base system is still supported, but your desktop and gui programs aren't (unless you are using ones from on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS install media; not Lubuntu)  http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2019/03/01/ubuntu-16-04-6-lts-released/

Comment: @guiverc I'm not sure what you're getting at there. Not sure how that relates to restoring my old theme.

Comment: I'm meaning Lubuntu 16.04 LTS (3 year support) reached EOL back in April, as did all other flavors of Ubuntu that wasn't Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (5 years), Kylin (5 years) or server (5 years).  ie. If you achieve what you want, you're system GUI hasn't been receiving updates since april-2019 (LXDE on 16.04 is EOL, MATE on 16.04 is EOL, XFCE on 16.04 is EOL, KDE on 16.04 is EOL etc), ie. if you're on the internet & not *stand-alone* - upgrading to a supported system (or switching to Unity which is supported on 16.04) is my recommendation.  https://lubuntu.me/xenial-released/

Comment: Also where did you newly download it from?  https://www.ubuntu.com/download/flavours will take you to the official Lubuntu site https://lubuntu.me/downloads/ which doesn't offer 16.04 (due to EOL status).   Did you even get it from an official site (yes it's possible, I checked a mirror found on https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+cdmirrors and did find it available, but I'd check where you downloaded it from as was it from an official site (lubuntu.me or ubuntu.com)  *note: lubuntu.net is a fan site, not a Lubuntu/Ubuntu managed site*

Comment: *Preferences* -> *Customize Look and Feel* lets you change settings in Lubuntu 18.04 (should be same as 16.04), however it looks like your picture also includes docky/plank and other non-Lubuntu/LXDE/LXQt add-ons (I happened to notice my Lubuntu 18.04 looks almost identical except for docky/plank add-ons.  If your current setup doesn't show icons or is still different make changes in *Desktop Preferences* too, or *OpenBox Configuration*

Comment: @guiverc thanks for all the input but i know about the customization options under preferences. The theme I am used to is not there. That is my issue. I know there's other add-ons in that picture, that's not what I'm talking about though **i just want to know what the name of the old theme and icons are** if yours looks the same please tell me the name of the specific themes/icons you are using. P.S. http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/

Comment: The panel/icon-theme set looks like Lubuntu-dark-panel, widget Clearlooks, both being standard options.

Comment: @guiverc nope, i found out the icon theme is called **nuoveXT**, theme still unknown